# How to hide the option menu when using getSupportFragment

Tags: android, optionmenu

Good Morning Guys,

i am trying to hide the option menu on some fragment.For the example i just want the option menu show on Promotion page

[image]

i add the code in the promotion.java

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu,MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu);

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
}
```

and then i want to hide on other fragment.

when i launching the app and the first fragment is like [image]

but when i click to the promotion page and click back to the menu page and the action bar will be like this

[image]

i am using getSupportFragment to call the menu item, and this problem just only happen on the fragment using the getSupportFragment call out.

```
case R.id.menu:
                 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new MenuFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to control the option menu from `Fragment` you must call `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in `onCreate()` of the `Fragment`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

Clear the `menu` from`onCreateOptionsMenu()`:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.clear();
}
```

**OR,** you can `show/hide` specific menu `item` by overriding `onPrepareOptionsMenu`:

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.your_menu_item);
    item.setVisible(false);
}
```

Comment: it's work but i want the option menu just show on promotion page, and it will be hide on another fragment. i try this already but when i go back to promotion page, the option menu is hide

Comment: Do the same thing in your Promotion fragment. In onPrepareOptionsMenu use item.setVisible(true); also use setHasOptionsMenu(true) in onCreate() method of Promotion fragment.

Comment: If my answer seems usefule please give up vote. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the fragment onCreate add  setHasOptionsMenu(true)

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

then

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
MenuItem item=menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);//your id instead of action_search
item.setVisible(false);
}
```